# Brother network scanner stopped working after 20.04 update

Tags: 20.04, scanner

I have DCP-1610W which used to work just fine using Simple Scan before upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.

brscan-skey seems to think it's fine

```
➜ brscan-skey -l
DCP-1610W         : brother4:net1;dev0  : 192.168.2.184        Active
```

brsaneconfig4  as well

```
➜ brsaneconfig4 -q
...
Devices on network
  0 DCP-1610W           "DCP-1610W"         I:192.168.2.184
```

and it looks like all the drivers are up to date

```
➜ dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                    1.0.2                                      all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                0.2.4-1                                    amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                    0.4.5-1                                    amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  dcp1610wcupswrapper:i386                   3.0.1-1                                    i386         Brother DCP-1610W CUPS wrapper driver
ii  dcp1610wlpr:i386                           3.0.1-1                                    i386         Brother DCP-1610W LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     6-1build1                                  amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4.2-3                                    amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

It's just that Simple Scan (now Document Scanner) says `No scanners detected` after a brief search.

All the similar posts suggest the fixes which I have already had to apply to get the scanner working in 18.04, like making sure that the drivers found in `/usr/lib64/sane/` are also available under `/usr/lib/sane`

Comment: Did you add your 'username' to the group lp?  `sudo adduser <username> lp`?

Comment: @oscar1919 Yep, both lp and lpadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

List of sane backends in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` got moved to `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf.dpkg-old` during upgrade, and the "new" one didn't contain `brother4` backend.

I've added it and now the scanner gets found by frontends.