# How to manually specify document scanner IP address

Tags: 20.04, scanner, document, subnet

Recently fresh/clean installed from 16.04 (to 20.04), where I was able to use the document scanner app to drive my Brother document scanner.

I'm trying to use the (Gnome) Document Scanner app on 20.04 and it's saying "No scanners detected".

This is likely because my scanner is on a different sub-network, but I can't find an option in "Preferences" to manually specify the IP address of the scanner.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1272787/1222991)? It looks to be very similar to your issue. 

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify that I did a fresh/clean install, not an upgrade. So that other answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot that I had run a shell command at some point on 16.04 to get it to work:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=FRIENDLY-NAME model=MODEL-NAME ip=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Not sure what it does, but it's done the trick for 20.04 as well.

*Note: This is after installing the relevant Brother scanner drivers.*